# How to hide title of two different groups of Isotope elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, jquery-isotope

I'm working with Isotope to filter two different groups of elements (National and International categories), with both buttons and search.

On top of each group of elements I've got a title of each category.

How can I hide the title if all the elements under it's category are hidden (each filtered elements gets a `display: none;` property)?

For example, if all of the "International" elements get filtered (either by search or button) I also want to hide the div element with the title "International".

Here's a CodePen with my code: https://codepen.io/koiastudio/pen/KrYMWm

Not sure what is the best approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See updated CodePen for solution

```
// Hide or show categories titles based on articles visibility
function projects_title() {
    var $title = $('.projects-title');
    $title.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.next('.entry-content').find('article:visible').length) {
            $this.css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $this.css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
}

$grid_projects.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
    projects_title();
});
```